# Why Android saves state of EditText, but not TextView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

In Android project, I am trying to find out how the state saving works when I am navigating between fragments (by `NavHostFragment`).

Let's say I have fragment A and fragment B:

- Fragment A includes one button, one textView and one editText
- Fragment A have single argument `ARG_IS_EDITABLE` (boolean)
- If fragment is created with argument set to `true`, I am programatically changing value of those three views I mentioned.
- After that I set `arguments = null`

Now, clicking on the button triggers navigation to fragment B.

When I then click back (popBackStack), text in EditText is restored, but textView's nor Button's text is restored.

Does Android calls `onSaveInstanceState()` selectively just for some types of widgets? Can I somehow force it to also save state of e.g. TextView?

I am basically trying to avoid setting the values everytime I return from fragment B.

PS: For more context, real example is that you have form fragment (A) and when you click on some button, you are navigated to somne fragment what includes list of selectables (B). You select one selectable from list, set fragment result and pop back stack back to A.

Answer (score 2):

The text in a `TextView` or `Button` is often static and provided directly from a string resource. It is more rare to dynamically change the text on either of these.

On the other hand, the text in an `EditView` is entered by the user, so its value will change at run time.

I imagine that the Android developers chose to automatically call `onSaveInstanceState()` on the `EditView`, but not the `TextView` or `Button`.

Comment: I also imagine thats the case, but I am trying to find in code the condition and hopefully find a way how to force it for my case, without too much additional code.

Comment: You can always implement your own `onSaveInstanceState()`. @Baterka

Answer (score 2):

During `TextViews` `onSaveInstanceState` it checks its [`getFreezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getFreezesText()) property to determine whether text should be persisted or not (its `false` by default).

You can change it programatically with [`setFreezesText(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setFreezesText(boolean)) or through xml with [`android:freezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:freezesText) property.

`EditText` is saving by default because it overrides `getFreezesText` to always return true.

---

As for how saving is performed in general - all views that have an ID set are saved. You are free to disable it per view basis by using [`setSaveEnabled(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSaveEnabled(boolean)) property which stops `onSaveInstanceState` from being called.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases where this scenario might behave differently

1. **Navigated to `B` using `replace`**, in this case when the `views` gets destroyed once you leave the `fragment` but fragment instance and `arguments` are preserved, so on popping stack it recreates all three views and fails to set text as `arguments is null` but as `Edittext's` state is preserved in `savedinstancestate`, it is automatically populated for you! If you want to achieve same for `TextView`, add `android:freezesText="true"` to your `TextView`. It saves and restores text for you! Here is doc :
   [freezesText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AfreezesText)
2. **Navigated to `B` using `add`**, in this case fragment view hierarchy is intact and would be resumed as is one the stack pops!